# Stop browser loading indicator iframe

Tags: javascript, html, browser

is it possible to stop the browser indicator on a iframe src. In this case its pointing to a different domain happens after page load so don't want to show the indicator

Comment: What do you mean "indicator"?

Comment: I meant the browser tab spinner, status bar

Comment: Here is a doc about the spinner: [http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=20663](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=20663) Not sure if it answers your question.